# How to create buckets with Micrometer

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, metrics, micrometer

My understanding of Micrometer is still fairly small, so I will start by presenting what I'm actually trying to achieve.

**Purpose**

- Given that I have records within a database table, with each record containing a "creation_date".
- Given the client calls an API to fetch these records
- I would like to record how many times a record was accessed grouped by it's creation date (just month and year)

**Example Outcome**

- In the last 6 hours, 10 records created in January 2021 were accessed
- In the last 12 hours, 15 records created in February 2021 were accessed
- Between last monday and last tuesday, 5 records created in February 2021 were accessed

**What I thought of**

- A counter for each month/year combination, which gets incremented whenever a record of the same month/year creation date was accessed

The issue with this approach if I'm not mistaken, is the number of counters that must be created, for the past, and for the future.

I was thinking if there could be some kind of a bucket support within Micrometer as in:

- If the record accessed was created in January 2021 -> Store it in bucket A (labeled January 2021)
- If the record accessed was created in February 2022 -> Store it in bucket B (labeled February 2022)

I am not sure if I'm looking into the right direction to achieve this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you'll most likely not want to do this aggregation within micrometer but within the metrics backend in which you ship your metrics to. Which metric backend are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Check the docs and read about dimensionality and Tags: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts

If I understand your issue correctly, you want counters that has a tag (label) that shows you the month it was accessed, here's an example:

```java
public class TagsDemo {
    private static final SimpleMeterRegistry registry= new SimpleMeterRegistry();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Counter accessCounter = Counter.builder("accessed")
                    .tag("year", getAccessedYear())
                    .tag("month", getAccessedMonth())
                    .register(registry);
            accessCounter.increment();
        }

        System.out.println(registry.getMetersAsString());
    }

    private static String getAccessedYear() {
        return "202" + (int)(Math.random() * 2); // 2020, 2021
    }

    private static String getAccessedMonth() {
        return "0" + ((int)(Math.random() * 2) + 1); // 01, 02
    }
}
```

This produces 4 time series (2020-01, 2020-02, 2021-01, 2021-02):

```
accessed(COUNTER)[month='01', year='2021']; count=1.0
accessed(COUNTER)[month='02', year='2021']; count=3.0
accessed(COUNTER)[month='01', year='2020']; count=4.0
accessed(COUNTER)[month='02', year='2020']; count=2.0
```

On your backend, you can query (I make up a query language since I don't know your registry):

- What is the total: `sum(accessed)`
- What is the total in 2021: `sum(accessed WHERE year=2021)`
- What is the total in 2021-01: `sum(accessed WHERE year=2021 AND month=01)`

Of course you can add just one tag like `.tag("date", getAccessedDate())` (`2021-01`) and query that: `sum(accessed WHERE date=2021-01)` but that can prevent you being able to query the year and the month separately.